# Ongoing Notification Disappears When Clearing Memory

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

My problem is I want to cancel an ongoing notification only if cancel
   option is selected in the app, but whenever I clear memory on "Task
   Manager/RAM" tab of my android device my notification disappears.

What can I do to make my ongoing notification stay even if I clear memory?

I created an ongoing notification in a class that extends `BroadcastReciever` class.In my OnGoingNotificationReciever(extends BroadcastReciever):

```
Intent mainAct =  new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 555, mainAct, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(resID).setContentTitle(city).setContentText(temperature);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(1,  mBuilder.build());
```

Then I set an `AlarmManager` to start this BroadcastReciever and repeat every 5 minutes:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent i7 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OnGoingNotificationReciever.class);
PendingIntent ServiceManagementIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1111111, i7, 0);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 5 * 60 * 1000, ServiceManagementIntent);
```

This works perfectly and does what I want to do(e.g when I close the app, notification stays on the status bar) except it disappears when clearing memory.

Note: In [**Yahoo Weather**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.weather) application it does what I want to do, but I couldn't find how on the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search I finally found a solution to this problem.

In my Manifest.xml I wrote the following:

```
<receiver android:name=".OnGoingNotificationReciever" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" android:path="com.example.havadurumumenu" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

`PACKAGE_RESTARTED` is called when you clear memory, and setting this restarts your receiver after clearing memory.