# Avoid destroying of Service

Tags: android, service

How to avoid my service not to be destroyed by the memory cleaning applications(i.e. clean master). I want my service to be running always. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: run a foregorund service. Battery may drain out if you keep service running for long duration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908661/ongoing-notification-disappears-when-clearing-memory

Comment: @Raghunandan setting a service as a "foreground" one doesn't drain your battery out

Comment: @pskink agreed. yes i suggested its is not good to keep the service running for long

Comment: @Raghunandan you can have a foreground service running all the time without any damage,  for instance a foreground service can be started at boot time and if you don't stop it it's started,  the fact it is started doesn't mean it drains your battery out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to make it a [Foreground Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground).
It keeps an ongoing notification in the notification area, and the system gives a high priority to the process. I'm mot sure whether this will save it from "Task Managers", though.

Answer (score 0):

You should do 2 things:

1. Make your service as Foreground service. which means some/any part of your activity as visible. Android doesn't kill anything which is visible to user.
2. Make your service as STICKY.