# Run function when app is closed - Android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

I want to show the user constantly an ongoing notification that doesn't disappear when the user kills the app in the "task manager". The problem is that when this happens (the user kills the app in the "task manager") the ongoing notification disappears. As a solution, I want to resend the notification when the app gets killed by the user or from android itself. I tried to handle this with a BroadcastReciever connected with the PACKAGE_RESTARTED action (like suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25909283/10094065)), but it doesn't work (the sysout doesn't get called). Any solutions?

My BroadcastReciever:

```
package com.appstiq.flutter_app;

public class AutoConnection extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /*This function should be called when the app is killed
          so that I can resend the notification */ 
        System.out.println("It works!");
    }
}
```

Part of my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name="com.appstiq.flutter_app.AutoConnection">
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED"/>
            <data android:scheme="package" android:path="com.appstiq.flutter_app"/>
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I look forward to helpful answers :D

Comment: Your `<intent-filter>` does not match that from the answer that you cited. Also note that the documentation for that broadcast has "Note that the restarted package does not receive this broadcast".

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay thanks, I fixed it but it still doesn't work. Do you know any way how to achieve this (an ongoing notification that never disappears)?

Comment: I doubt that there is a solution that works across devices from all manufacturers. Having your service with the ongoing notification be in a separate process from your UI may help.

Comment: It actually is called from an alarm service and in the emulator everything works fine but on a real device is doesn't work. So is it impossible?

Comment: "It actually is called from an alarm service" -- I do not know what "it" is in that sentence. Note that Doze mode, app standby, and various manufacturer-specific power management features will interfere with the operation of `AlarmManager`. "So is it impossible?" -- I stand by my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65969310/run-function-when-app-is-closed-android?noredirect=1#comment116638632_65969310), if your concern is your notification going away when the user gets rid of your task (e.g., via the overview screen).

Comment: "It" means the "sendNotification" function. Okay, it is a pity that it cannot be implemented. Thanks for your help!